# Online compiler input

Tags: python, input, jupyter

For a project I am using the pyodide backed Jupyter lite (https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/lab/index.html). I am aware that there are many other online compilers but I can't use them.

Whenever, I use the input command in Python and try to print the variable value it gives me an object promise as an output. (Check sample code)

```
str1 = input("Enter your name: ")

print(str1)

Output:

[Object Promise]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.